# Configuring Airflow to run DAGs as user with a common DB

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

We have a farm managed through [Platform LSF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=overview-lsf-introduction). The loadsharing is per user basis and the no user has sudo privileges on any machines.

I would like to configure Airflow such that different users can run the DAGs they want (on allocated machines) as themselves while the bookkeeping about each DAG, triggers, schedule is common to all users. Is this possible?

Tried airflow standalone as well as a docker managed instance of Airflow. But in the latter I did not schedule the jobs on the farm through LSF